# Zero initialization of non-POD

Tags: c++

Why in the following non-POD class the x is initalized to zero?

```
class test {
public:
    void print() {
        cout << x << endl;
    }
private:
    int x;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    test * tst = new test();
    tst->print();
    cout << is_pod<test>::value << endl;
}
```

Both tst->print() and is_pod() returns 0

Comment: It may be not initialized and just happens to be 0.

Comment: Debug or release build?

Comment: When I make print a vritual function, the x is a random number but in the code posted above it is always zero

Comment: Uninitialized variables have an *indeterminate* value. Indeterminate doesn't mean "random" or "garbage" (though it can be), just that the value is unknown. Using an indeterminate value leads to undefined behavior. However, in this case `x` *isn't* uninitialized.

Comment: the standard doesn't force non-pod pod members  to be initialized with random values. compilers might still zero init memory depending on a mountain of factors.

Comment: Isnt this cos of Debug?

Comment: For both Debug and Release it works the same

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a result of [value-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) of a class without a user-provided constructor.

In this case, `T()` and `new T()` perform zero-initialization first:

> if `T` is a class type with a default constructor that is neither user-provided nor deleted (that is, it may be a class with an implicitly-defined or defaulted default constructor), the object is **zero-initialized** and then it is default-initialized if it has a non-trivial default constructor;

The effects of [zero-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization) are:

> if `T` is an non-union class type, all base classes and **non-static data members are zero-initialized**, and all padding is initialized to zero bits. The constructors, if any, are ignored.

and

> if `T` is a scalar type, the object's initial value is the integral constant zero explicitly converted to `T`.

Comment: wrong. this is still default-initialized. the quote say so.

Comment: @UmNyobe "it is default-initialized ***if** it has a non-trivial default constructor*" Also, since the members already are initialized (because of the previous zero initialization) then would default-initialization really matter (since it won't remove or cancel out the previous initialization)?

Comment: @UmNyobe The created object of `test` is _value-initialized_, due to `new test()`. This _zero-initiliazes_ members. The corresponding paragraph of the Standard is [dcl.init/8.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init#8.2).

Comment: Why is it value-initialized? It says [on cpprefence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new): `if initializer is absent, the object is default-initialized`. Not value-initalized. Thank you @underscore_d So `test *tst = new test;` would be default-initialized.

Comment: @KamilCuk But the initialiser is **not** absent. It is present as an empty initialiser `()`. This is specifically called out, for example, [on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization). There is a difference here between providing no initialiser and providing an empty one. (This is why you always provide an initialiser and don't worry about this quirk.)

Comment: So the class will be first zero initalized and then the compiler genrated default constructor will be called?

Comment: @michalt38, in the general case - yes. But in this particular case the implicitly-defined default constructor is trivial (does nothing), so it won't be called.

Comment: @Evg you are partially right. new T() will peform zero init. T{} will perform zero init. T() will **not** perform zero init. see the effects of value initialization 1) and 2) https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization

Comment: @UmNyobe, `T()` will also perform zero-initialization first (in certain cases it might also declare a function that returns `T` thanks to most vexing parse). Note that `X)`es in the "Effects" section just enumerate items of the list (1, 2, 3, 4), they have no relation to `(X)`es in the "Syntax" section. All the effects listed there apply to both `T()`, and `new T()`. See also the [standard draft, \[dcl.init\]#8](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#8).